# SAPUI5 mock server doesn't receive requests

Tags: javascript, request, sapui5, mockserver

I didn't find a solution for this problem. I'm currently working with the *CRUD Master-Detail Application* *WebIDE* template and added some custom functions with *OData* calls. When running the app with mock server it loads the mock data. So far so good. But if I send a read request to the mock server it `throws a 404 not found error`.

**Request URL**

```
https://webidetesting[...].dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/here/goes/your/serviceurl/MyEntity(12345)
```

Here's the mock server part in my `index` file `flpSandboxMockServer.html`:

```
<script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {

            sap.ui.require([
                "my/project/localService/mockserver"
            ], function (mockserver) {
                // set up test service for local testing
                mockserver.init();

                // initialize the ushell sandbox component
                sap.ushell.Container.createRenderer().placeAt("content");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The OData read call looks like:

```
onRemoveMyEntityBtnPress: function () {
        let oEntityTable = this.byId("lineItemsList");
        let aSelectedItems = oEntityTable.getSelectedItems();
        let oModel = this.getModel();

        for (let oSelectedItem of aSelectedItems) {
            let sBindingPath = oSelectedItem.getBindingContext().getPath();
            let sGuid = this._selectGuidFromPath(sBindingPath);

            this._loadEntityFromService(sGuid, oModel).then((oData) => {
                // Next step: change a property value
            }).catch((oError) => {
                jQuery.sap.log.error(oError);
            });
        }

        if (oModel.hasPendingChanges()) {
            oModel.submitChanges();
        }
    },
_loadEntityFromService: function (sGuid, oModel) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            oModel.read(`/MyEntity(${sGuid})`, { 
                success: (oData) => {
                    resolve(oData);
                },
                error: (oError) => { // call always ends up here with 404 error
                    reject(oError);
                }
            });
        });
    },
```

Does someone have an idea what I else have to do to send my read request to the mock service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution!
I used the OData entity type to read my entity. I changed the destination to my entity set and now it doesn't throw a 404 error.